# CPU Utilisation 100% after reindexing

Tags: solr

We are experiencing CPU utilization going to 100% after starting to rebuild the indexes in Sitecore.
Earlier, it worked fine but there was a server outage and since then, we are experiencing the HIGH CPU Utilization.

This is mainly on the CM server and we have different CM, CD and SOLR servers.

Comment: Does your server meet the recommended specs? What version are you on? 
If you restart the solr service does the CPU go down? Then try triggering a rebuild and see if it jumps up again to 100.

Comment: You can try this https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6360/why-does-rebuilding-a-search-index-peg-my-cpu-at-100